# Length of Multinormal Distribution

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

Let $X \in R^n$ be a random normally distributed vector with $E X = \mu$ and $\text{Var } X = \Sigma$. Is there a neat way to calculate the variation of $|X|$, the length of $X$? I know how to calculate $E |X| = |\mu|$. But unsure about the variation.

Comment: What makes you think $E|X|=|\mu|$, especially if $\mu$ is zero and $\Sigma$ is not?

Comment: Of course, if $\mu = 0$ and $\Sigma$ is the identity matrix, then the squared length of $X$ is $Chisq(n).$ If $\mu$ is nonzero and the var-cov matrix is the identity, then the squared length is a noncentral chi-squared distribution. I imagine an expression for the general possibly correlated case will be a bit messy.

Comment: Yes, it is easy if $\mu$ or $\sigma$ are nice (i.e. identity, 0, etc.) but in general is there a solution?